# AvalonEdit for ironPython Scripts?

Tags: c#, wpf, ironpython, avalonedit

Is it possible to use AvalonEdit control in a WPF application as an ironPython script editor? The requirement is to have syntax highlighting and inline script validation. If possible having intellisense would be even better. If not AvalonEdit, please suggest any other such controls (even if commercial) which can be useful for this purpose.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do that [look at example](http://jonsblogat.blogspot.com/2011/06/adding-scripting-support-to-wpf.html)

Comment: Thanks Dima.. that's what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

You can find a definition for color highlightning here: [Python.xshd](https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/blob/master/FreePIE.GUI/Common/AvalonEdit/Python.xshd)